# How to connect a 2 wire 240v power inverter to a 3 wire 240/120v house

Tags: wiring

I recently bought an off-grid solar system from China but I was not aware that the inverter has 2 wire 240v input/output. How can I  connect it to my house?

Comment: Most grid-tied solar inverters either don't have a neutral or have a "dummy" neutral that isn't really meant to carry any current. It's possible that your inverter is meant for US 240 V, 60 Hz split-phase, in which case it'd be as simple as backfeeding a 2-pole breaker. I get the feeling it's not quite right, though. Post a picture of the electrical specs on the label (if they exist)

Answer (score 2):

I’m going to assume you’re in North America, with split-phase 120/240 volt service.

The answer is you can’t, at least not directly.  If you were to connect the inverter to your two hots, it would be the equivalent of losing your neutral. Search this site or the web for “open neutral” and you’ll see how dangerous that is.

In theory, you could use a 1-to-1 isolation transformer, with a center-tapped secondary to provide the neutral. Make sure it’s rated for the voltage and current (not to mention the line frequency) of the inverter.

Let’s talk about other issues.

For one thing, I wouldn’t be caught dead with that rig connected to my house! Read about all of the poorly designed and manufactured crap coming out of China these days. You are literally playing with fire.

Second, you say this is an off-grid inverter (glad you’re not trying to use a grid-tie inverter). Are you actually off-grid or just looking for backup? How are you planning to tie in to the house if you are normally on the grid? Flipping off the main breaker and flipping on the breaker to the inverter without any kind of interlock is dangerous and clearly against code. Either use a generator transfer switch or an interlock.

Last of all, don’t expect your homeowner’s insurance to be very happy when you make a claim. This rig is most likely not legal to be installed in the US.

Comment: The transformer you're referring to is common as dirt.  It typically has switchable 240 OR 480 on the primary, and 120/240 on the secondary.  In the US a 5kVA size can be had for about $100 on Craigslist.  It will be American though, it won't catch fire or fail in 6 months. **The bigger problem is the output will be 50Hz, which many US appliances will not like**.  This entire solar system is poorly specced and is bound to fail.  When this happens, don't get disgusted with solar, get disgusted with Chinese gear and hasty design.

Comment: @Harper -- if they load the system down heavily -- the fact the Cheese inverter puts out 50Hz might actually light the transformer up...

Comment: A full isolation transformer is unnecessary. An autotransformer will do the job for synthesizing neutral from a 240V-only inverter. There are legitimate UL-listed inverters that offer an autotransformer accessory for grid-down backup use.